# SQL Alchemy - How to use built-in function in PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want put this query into code:

```
select * from st_geomfromtext('POINT(106.69588536141288 10.782847409207672)')
```

Here is what I did in code:

```
class st_geomfromtext(GenericFunction):
    name = 'st_geomfromtext'

query = Session.query(func.st_geomfromtext('POINT(106.69588536141288 10.782847409207672)')).all()
```

Here is what I receive:

```
LINE 1: SELECT st_geomfromtext('POINT(106.69588536141288 10.78284740...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to validate your query directly against PostgreSQL?

Function may actually not be there. st_geomfromtext is part of [PostGIS](https://postgis.net), depending on the PostgreSQL version, you may need to install / enable it.